# etag and last modified headers for django app not being set

Tags: django, caching

I am trying to set the etag header using the condition decorator with Django 1.3.

I am using the following:

```
@condition(etag_func=profile_etag, last_modified_func=profile_last_modified)
@require_person_viewed_is_verified
def profile(request, id):
    """
    Return profile for person id.
    If profile is not verified only staff and self can view.
    """
    user = request.user
    ...
```

with a middleware classes of

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',

    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',

    'johnny.middleware.LocalStoreClearMiddleware',
    'johnny.middleware.QueryCacheMiddleware',

#    'django.middleware.cache.CacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.http.ConditionalGetMiddleware',

    'pybb.middleware.PybbMiddleware',
)

USE_ETAGS = True
```

I am not getting the etag or last modified headers being set in the http response.  Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

I was using CharlesProxy (which is a great tool btw) and I had no caching enabled! School boy error I know!